# Losing Cookies and Session Variables during AuthorizeCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-variables, custom-authentication

I'm currently working on getting a test environment stood up (it is currently called DEV) and am experiencing some weird issues.

When you first come to the site, we have an agreement page.  Hitting the "I Agree" button will force the user through an Action to check to see if they are a member of the site already or not.  We do use a demo mode also, but that is not part of the issue.

The issue I'm currently experiencing is the following.  Initially in the Action, we create a Cookie called "siteaccept".  Once that is created, we determine if the site is in demo mode or not, then move on to getting the user (actual user or demo user).  Once the user is found, we log their Id in a Cookie called "cntPOC", and also create a Session variable by the same name with the same data (original developers wrote much of this convoluted logic which I want to change before someone asks why keep a Session and Cookie).  We then do a RedirectToAction to the Action to bring up the main page of the site.

Here is where the issue comes into play.  The main page of the site's Action has a CustomAuthorizeAttribute decoration on it.  In our CustomAuthorizeAttribute class, we have OnAuthorizion and AuthorizeCore being overrode.  OnAuthorizion fires off first, however, it uses base.OnAuthorization.  Once that is called, AuthorizeCore is called.  In AuthorizeCore, we check for the "siteaccept" Cookie, followed by a check on the "cntPOC" Session variable.  If both are there, we return true, otherwise false if either fails.

On not only my local environment but the DBA's, this works without a hitch.  I see our Cookies and Session variable.  However, on our DEV environment, both the Cookies and Session variable are missing.  We have IE 11 configured to allow Cookies, yet we cannot get them once we leave the Action and proceed into the CustomAuthorizeAttribute.

I did find I can find the Cookie today if I check HttpContext.Current.Response instead of HttpContext.Current.Request, but that is the incorrect way to do it obviously.

Below is my code.  I'm fairly certain since the code works on my local environment, it should be fine in our DEV environment.  Also a quick note, our production environment does work, so the code obviously functions.  It's a question now of why does the DEV environment not.

MainController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection frmCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Cookies.Remove("bracmisaccept");

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("bracmisaccept");
            cookie.Value = "true";
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            ...

            //Demo Mode
            var poc = new HttpCookie("cntPOC");
            cookie.Value = "7578";
            Response.Cookies.Add(poc);

            Session["cntPOC"] = 7578;

            return RedirectToAction("ApplicationSelection");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError("Main Index", ex);
            return PartialView(@"../Error/ExceptionHandling");
        }
   }

   [CustomAuthorizeAttribute]
   public ActionResult ApplicationSelection()
   {
        return View();
   }
```

CustomAuthorizeAttribute.cs

```
        public string RedirectUrl = "~/Main/SessionTimeout";
        public string CookieExpiredRedirectUrl = "~/Main/Index";
        public string AjaxRedirectUrl = "~/Error/AjaxError";
        private bool _isAuthorized;
        private bool _isCookieExpired;

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["siteaccept"] == null)
            {
                _isAuthorized = false;
                _isCookieExpired = true;
                return false;
            }

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["cntPOC"] == null)
            {
                _isAuthorized = false;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if (!_isAuthorized)
            {
                if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(_isCookieExpired)
                        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(CookieExpiredRedirectUrl);
                    else
                        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(RedirectUrl);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm fairly certain the code is fine, but I did read in a few articles that AuthorizeCore may or may not have the Cookies and Session variables at times.  I just wanted to find out if I'm wasting my time with changing the code or if it's the box we have this site on.  The server is super locked down, so yeah, kind of annoying...

Edit:  I have yet to figure out how to fix this yet, however, I did find if I do a publish on this code, I can enter into the site properly.  I still cannot run localhost to inspect the site, but a publish fixes a few minor issues of whether things will work on this site.